# Error on "storage/framework/services.json" laravel 5 project

Tags: laravel-5

I have a project in laravel 5 in my notebook (windows), I created a repository for it in bitbucket and decided to use on my desktop (ubuntu 14). But for some reason they are showing several errors. And I'm new in version 5, I searched but could not understand the reason for the errors.

My .gitignore:

```
vendor/
node_modules/

# Laravel 4 specific
bootstrap/compiled.php
app/storage/

# Laravel 5 & Lumen specific
bootstrap/cache/
storage/
.env.*.php
.env.php
.env

# Rocketeer PHP task runner and deployment package. https://github.com/rocketeers/rocketeer
.rocketeer/
```

After cloning a repository within the htdocs of xampp, I used the following commands:

1) composer install

2) chmod 777 -R storage

3) chmod 777 -R bootstrap

but when opening http://localhost/myProject/public/

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
>
> 1/1 ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 75:
>   file_put_contents(/opt/lampp/htdocs/myProject/storage/framework/services.json):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Run the commands the correct way:

2. `chmod -R 777 storage`
3. `chmod -R 777 bootstrap`

i.e. the `-R` flag needs to come after chmod.